# JSCS Exclude folders recursively but not some sub-folders

Tags: javascript, jscs

I recently started to apply JSCS to a project, the project has existing source code, but i don't want apply to all, only the new code I write from this moment and when I make changes to existing files

I'm using the exclusion feature on the configuration

```
"jscsConfig": {
    "preset": "airbnb",
    "excludeFiles": [
      "foldera/**",
      "node_modules/**",
      "folderb/**",
      "folderc/**",
      "folderd/**"
    ]
  }
```

But How I can exclude all subfolders from `folder` except those I want

E.g. I want exclude folderd recursively except `folderd/subfolder2`

```
folderd/
  file1.js
  file2.js
  subfolder1/
  subfolder2/
    file3.js
    file4.js
  subfolder3/
```